# Click() event is called twice inside Jquery Mobile collapsible

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, click, jquery-mobile-collapsible

**Background**: I'm loading some resources via `ajax`, using promisses with `$.when.apply`, doing other requisitions when the previous are done. I'm  dynamically loading some `jQuery Mobile Collapsibles` and some content inside them.

When I click in a specific content with  a link, he have to open his destination and save an value of a custom atribute that I created to store data(`data-id`).

**Problem**: Each time that I open another collapsible, then click in this link inside, the click is called 1 time *PLUS* the number of diferents collapsibles that I opened previously, and consequently leading to error, that is calling the requisitions multiple times.

Here's an image to make more clear:
[image: error]

CODE:

```
$.when.apply(null, [buildTasks(curr_user)]).done(function () {
         //make the requisition. If it's not empty, then...   
               if( !isEmpty( $('#posts_dates') ) ){

                   $('#pg_tasks').on("collapsibleexpand", "[data-role=collapsible]", function (e) {

                       /*Checks if the collapsible have data inside
                       a custom created attribute, data-date
                       If yes, saves this data in a variable(temp_data),
                       do the ajax requisition , empty temp_data and     empty 
                      data-date, so the requisition won't be called again for this collapsible .*/

                      if ( $(this).attr('data-date') !== '' ){

                          var temp_data = $(this).attr('data-date');
                          var temp_id = $(this).attr('id');


                           buildTasksPosts(curr_user,temp_data,temp_id); 
                           //loads the content via ajax when a     collapsible is expanded

                              temp_data = '';
                              temp_id = '';
                              $(this).attr('data-date','');


                          $.when.apply(null, [buildTasksPosts() ]).done(function () {

                   /*after the requisition is done, enable a handler 
                     on the current page for the links with a custom attribute data-id*/


                             $( "#pg_tasks" ).on( "click","a[data-id]", function() {
                                    var p_id = '';

                                    //THE ERROR can be seen here when I use the console 
                                    console.log('DATA-ID: '+ $( this ).attr('data-id') );
                                    p_id = $( this ).attr('data-id');

                                    buildTasksDetail(p_id);
                            });

                          });


                      }else{
                          console.log('AVISO:não fiz nada!!');
                      }



                   });

               }//end if 

        });
```

Any ideas? I really don't know what is causing this.

Comment: are you sure that this is the proper div? $( "#pg_tasks" ), all childeren within this div will generate a click event

Comment: because you have `click` inside `collapsibleexpand`, the latter event will multiple `click` listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a click handler to all `"a[data-id]"` children of `$("#pg_tasks")` every time a collapsible is expanded. That is why your click events keep firing plus one times.

Instead of adding the click handler within the `collapsibleexpand` of each collapsible, you can add it just once and let **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** work. So as soon as #pg_tasks exists in the DOM, you can attach the handler:

```
$( "#pg_tasks" ).off("click","a[data-id]").on( "click","a[data-id]", function() {
    var p_id = '';
    //THE ERROR can be seen here when I use the console 
    console.log('DATA-ID: '+ $( this ).attr('data-id') );
    p_id = $( this ).attr('data-id');
    buildTasksDetail(p_id);
 });
```

Event delegation allows the handler to work for matching DOM elements that are added dynamically after the handler is created.

Comment: Thank you very much, friend! I did this and it works!